# bootstrap-year-calendar... change popbox distance from text field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-year-calendar and when I click in the text field the popbox with the calendar selection shows up about 100px above the text field instead of directly at the text field? 
If the popbox appears below the text field, it shows up directly at the text field, the problem is only when it shows up above the text field...

Here is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetimepicker">Application deadline:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 300px;" id="datetimepicker">
</div>
```

and here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

since this is just following the minimal example I guess that there is some sort of collision with other parts of my code? 
Is there an option to modify the position of the popbox?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has the same problem... changing the html to this solved it for me...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label for="datetimepicker">Application deadline:    </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 300px;" id="datetimepicker_example">
    </div>
</div>
```

even though I don't know what is wrong with my original html?